# Render Permissions To HTML In Controller Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables, permissions

I have some html code in my controller for datatable actions (View , Edit & Delete)
So im busy working on permissions on a blade level. but now i'm struggling to render the same permissions to the HTML code that's in my controller.

I'm using this syntax on my blades

```
@if(Auth::user()->can('Add New Client'))
     <li><a href="{{ route('add.client') }}">Add New Client</a></li>
@endif
```

And in my controller i have this code with renders action icons on my datatables

```
$nestedData['action'] = "&emsp;<a href='{$show}' title='View more' class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i>&nbsp;View</a>
                               <a href='{$edit}' title='Edit details' class='btn btn-xs btn-success'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>&nbsp;Edit</a>";
```

So just like i did on the blade level i also want to have a permission on the datatable buttons (show & edit) to say

```
@if(Auth::user()->can('Edit Client'))
     <a href='{$edit}' title='Edit details' class='btn btn-xs btn-success'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>&nbsp;Edit</a>"
@endif
```

But when i put this code on the HTML in controller the code gets displayed on the form. I'm pretty new to laravel so any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "when i put this code on the HTML in controller" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(Auth::user()->can('Edit Client'))
<a href='{$edit}' title='Edit details' class='btn btn-xs btn-success'><i class='fa fa- pencil'></i>&nbsp;Edit</a>"@endif
```

I am not sure why you are using this code in conttroller. please use a template and add this code on it.

in the controller you don't need to use @